# Javascript Regex only replacing first match occurence

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am using regular expressions to do some basic converting of wiki markup code into copy-pastable plain text, and I'm using javascript to do the work.

However, javascript's regex engine behaves much differently to the ones I've used previously as well as the regex in Notepad++ that I use on a daily basis.

For example- given a test string:

```
==Section Header==
===Subsection 1===
# Content begins here.
## Content continues here.
```

I want to end up with:

```
Section Header
Subsection 1
# Content begins here.
## Content continues here.
```

Simply remove all equals signs.

I began with the regex setup of:

```
var reg_titles = /(^)(=+)(.+)(=+)/
```

This regex searches for lines that begin with one or more equals with another set of one or more equals. Rubular shows that it matches my lines accurately and does not catch equals signs in the middle of contet. http://www.rubular.com/r/46PrkPx8OB

The code to replace the string based on regex

```
var lines = $('.tb_in').val().split('\n'); //use jquery to grab text in a textarea, and split into an array of lines based on the \n 
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
  line_temp = lines[i].replace(reg_titles, "");
  lines[i] = line_temp; //replace line with temp
}
$('.tb_out').val(lines.join("\n")); //rejoin and print result
```

My result is unfortunately:

```
Section Header==
Subsection 1===
# Content begins here.
## Content continues here.
```

I cannot figure out why the regex replace function, when it finds multiple matches, seems to only replace the first instance it finds, not all instances.

Even when my regex is updated to:
    var reg_titles = /(={2,})/

"Find any two or more equals", the output is still identical. It makes a single replacement and ignores all other matches.

No one regex expression executor behaves this way for me. Running the same replace multiple times has no effect.

Any advice on how to get my string replace function to replace ALL instances of the matched regex instead of just the first one?

Comment: you probably aren't using the `g` flag to perform multiple (global) matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^=+|=+$
```

You can use this.Do not forget to add `g` and `m` flags.Replace by ``.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/28

Comment: I did not realize I had to set those flags, but it works perfectly, thank you very much. Also thanks for that site, it's definitely a step above rubular for reference!

Will accept your answer when the site allows me.

Comment: @ChrisRiley that's true.its a great site.try ,modify ,learn :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the `g` modifier to do a global search:

```
var reg_titles = /^(=+)(.+?)(=+)/g
```

Comment: Why you capture the starting anchor?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Basically because it was in the original code and did not influence. Anyway, it is already edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is needlessly complex, and yet doesn't actually accomplish what you set out to do. :) You might try something like this instead:

```
var reg_titles = /^=+(.+?)=+$/;
lines = $('.tb_in').val().split('\n');
lines.forEach(function(v, i, a) {
    a[i] = v.replace(reg_titles, '$1');
})
$('.tb_out').val(lines.join("\n"));
```